# Mule can't start as Window Service

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule-esb

When i start mule as window service, i check log and get this error.
Error message:

Mule installed.

--> Wrapper Started as Service

Launching a JVM...

Starting the Mule Container...

Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org

Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc. All Rights Reserved.

WARNING - Unable to load the Wrapper's native library because none of the

following files:

wrapper-windows-x86-64.dll

wrapper.dll

could be located on the following java.library.path:

D:\Programs\mule-standalone-3.9.0\bin%LD_LIBRARY_PATH%

D:\Programs\mule-standalone-3.9.0\lib\boot

Please see the documentation for the wrapper.java.library.path

configuration property.

System signals will not be handled correctly.

Error in WrapperListener.start callback. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load library. Reasons: [no jansi in java.library.path, C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\jansi-64.dll (The system cannot find the path specified)]

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load library. Reasons: [no jansi in java.library.path, C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\jansi-64.dll (The system cannot find the path specified)]

at org.fusesource.hawtjni.runtime.Library.doLoad(Library.java:184)

at org.fusesource.hawtjni.runtime.Library.load(Library.java:142)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved issue by creating the 'Temp' folder.
I've been testing with jdk 1.8.0_45.

C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp